# Converting MVC Model List to JSLINQ Error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have three dropdownlist BodyPart, ExamDetail and ExamView and I have complete data set for these lists. I don't need to call controller again and again whenever the dropdown change event call but I want to fetch list from my model's property list. I am using JS Library to apply LINQ Queryto avoid any loops in code. 
      My Class Architecture is given below:

```
public class BodyPart
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<ExamDetail> examdetail { get; set; }
}

public class ExamDetail
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<ExamView> examview { get; set; }
}

public class ExamView
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I have proper data in all my list, here is my js code to fetch ExamDetail Record

```
var selectedBodyPart = $("#BodyPartDDL").val();
var examdetailList   = JSLINQ(@Model.bodypart).Where(function (item) {
                       return item.ID == selectedBodyPart; });
```

But I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal(…)" error where I pass my model list. I need to pass this examdetailList to my ExamDetail partial view. Thank you.

Comment: Could your data contain a back-tick `\`` somewhere? This starts a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and if it isn't escaped correctly, you will likely get this error.

Comment: This is showing after the parenthesis  JSLINQ('HERE')  where I am passing this list

Comment: I don't have this back-tick in list data

Comment: This sounds like a Javascript error, which you can debug from the browser using the developer tools (press F12). The console should show you the [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError) and a [call stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack).

Comment: Are you using `@Model.bodypart` within a .cshtml page? I don't think it will work otherwise. Even within a .cshtml page, this might not work either. If you try `JSLINQ('[]')` do you also get an error?

Comment: Okay I will try this way too, yes it was showing on browser console.

Comment: JSLINQ('[@Model.bodypart]') you mean I should try this way ?